# Azure ServiceRuntime and Diagnostics v2.0.0.0?

Tags: azure, nuget, azure-storage, azure-web-roles, azure-configuration

I am getting the following error when running my web role:

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime, Version=2.0.0.0

In my references, I see that I am using version 1.8.0.0 of the `ServiceRuntime` (as well as `Diagnostics`).

I cannot find v2.0.0.0 in NuGet or anywhere on my computer.  I currently have the latest SDK installed.

How do I upgrade these two references to 2.0.0.0?

EDIT:

I am going to attempt to reinstall the SDK.  Which of the following do I need to uninstall?

[image]

My guess is just the `Libraries for .NET`?

Comment: You could run a full-text search for "1.8" over you working copy. It can be anywhere, for example, in web.config or in some abandoned files.

Comment: Thanks for the comment - really struggling with this problem.  I don't quite understand what you mean though.  Why am I searching for "1.8"?  I need to get v2.0.0.0

Comment: Yeap, you should search for "2.0", I really read your question backwards.

Comment: Ok thanks, but I still don't understand.  I need to get the new v2.0 DLLs.

Comment: Then I don't get your question. Do you want to use SDK 1.8 (and so get rid of references to 2.0) or do you want to use SDK 2.0 (which you clearly don't have installed)?

Comment: I want to know how and where to get v2.0.0.0 of ServiceRuntime and Diagnostics.  I have SDK 2.0 installed (I'm using the new storage libraries), but in my references list, I can only see v1.8 of ServiceRuntime and Diagnostics.

Comment: Something is big time wrong - with SDK 2.0 installed you should be able to add references to ServiceRuntime 2.0 no problem.

Comment: Oh damn.  Let me try uninstall and reinstall the SDK.  Feel free to turn that into an answer.

Comment: Question updated.. please check :)

Comment: When I was moving from 1.6 to 1.8 I uninstalled all the components with version 1.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to uninstall the SDK and reinstall it using the Web Platform installer.  I would have expected it to prompt for an upgrade or that there is a newer SDK out.  This was further confusing because I was using NuGet for the v2 of the Storage Libraries.